# Windows 2008 R2 Terminal Server - RemoteApp - Option "Start in" available?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, terminal, remoteapp

we have set up a Windows 2008 R2 Terminal Server. On this server, we want to run an application which needs another path for the option "Start in" than the application itself. In a shortcut, this is no problem (for example, the "Target" is C:\app\bin\application.exe and the "Start in:" is C:\app\users\user1). But I have no option for "Start in" when I configure the RemoteApp so the application fails to start.
Is there any possibility?

Thank you in advance

Frank

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any direct way to do that.
Workaround:

- Create batch file that goes to the start directory and then call the
  executable.
- Publish this batch instead of directly the executable.

This is not clean, but application that require a start in folder to work is bad too.
Use @echo off in your bat to make is more silent, and call your program with start so the batcj file don't wait your program to close.

You could also generate an executable to apply a custom icon to the published app.