# Remote App - linked exe

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

I'm experiencing below problem:

I'm trying to run Microsoft NAV as remote app. There are two exe file involved: `finsql.exe` - main executable and `finhlink.exe`. Later one is used to directly run a 'window' within NAV (it takes certain link as parameter). This functionality is not present in `finsql.exe`. After configuring and running `finhlink.exe` as remote app I get an error "...finsql.exe can't be executed...". I believe it's because `finhlink.exe` is in fact invoking `finsql.exe`.

Is there a way of allowing invocation of linked executable via remote app?

Answer (score 0):

To get a better picture, your should do a remote desktop to the server with a different login (admin one), and launch [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896645) from Sysinternals.
Filter on the user login used to test remote App.

Then launch your published App again. You may expect a file not found for the other executable.

You may have an issue with the starting folder. The first executable may try to launch the other from the current folder (from where it was started).

If so, you may do the same as i suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/376208/windows-2008-r2-terminal-server-remoteapp-option-start-in-available/376982#376982) on serverfault: publish a bath that go in the good folder before starting the executable.

Application can launch others even in remote app. For example, if i publish outlook and try to open a word document attached to a mail,it works.

Comment: Turns out the problem is with NAV itself and has been fixed in KB2489146.